# Show that if $\frac{x_i}{y_i}<t$ for all $i \leq n$, then $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_i}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}y_i}<t$

Tags: inequality, summation

How to show that if $\frac{x_i}{y_i}<t$ and $x_i,y_i>0$ for all $i \leq n$ , then $$\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}x_i}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}y_i}<t?$$

I tried the following

> If $\frac{x_i}{y_i}<t$ for all $i \leq n$, then $$\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}x_i}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}y_i} \leq \dfrac{n\max|x_i|}{n\max|y_i|}<t.$$

But that's obiviously incorrect, since we would have the last inequality for sure if $\max|x_i|$ was in the pair with $\max|y_i|$.

Comment: Have you a condition like $x_i,y_i \geqslant 0$?

Comment: Are there positivity constraints on the $y_i$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not elaborating.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=0}^n x_i < \sum_{i=0}^n ty_i$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $x_i<ty_i$ for each $i$, so
$$
\frac{\sum_i x_i}{\sum_i y_i} < \frac{\sum_i t y_i}{\sum_i y_i} = t.
$$
(This assumes $t>0$.)

Answer (score 0):

In general for rational numbers $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ with a,b,c,d positive and  $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$ we have $\frac{a}{b}$ < $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ < $\frac{c}{d}$

To see this for one side of the inequality $$\frac{a}{b} <\frac{c}{d}$$
$$da < bc$$
$$ da + cd < bc + cd$$
$$d(a+c) < c(b+d)$$
$$\frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$$

Now your problem follows because your sum is less than the largest value for $\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ which is less than t.